# Random forest algorithm not working for new datasets

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

I used random forest algorithm in python to train my dataset1 and I got an accuracy of 99%. But when I tried with the new dataset2 to predict the values, I am getting wrong values. I manually checked the results for the new dataset and when I compared with the prediction results, the accuracy is very low.

Below is my Code :

```
   from IPython import get_ipython
   get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

   import numpy as np
   import pandas as pd
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=(20.0,10.0)

   data = pd.read_csv('D:/Users/v477sjp/lpthw/Extract.csv', usecols=['CON_ID', 
   'CON_LEGACY_ID', 'CON_CREATE_TD',
   'CON_CREATE_LT', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_ORIG', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_CORIG',
   'BUL_CSYS_ID_DEST', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_CLEAR', 'TOP_ID', 'CON_DG_IN', 
   'PTP_ID', 'SMO_ID_1',
   'SMO_ID_8', 'LOB_ID', 'PRG_ID', 'PSG_ID', 'SMP_ID', 'COU_ISO_ID_ORIG',
   'COU_ISO_ID_DEST', 'CON_DELIV_DUE_DT', 'CON_DELIV_DUE_LT',
   'CON_POSTPONED_DT', 'CON_DELIV_PLAN_DT', 'CON_INTL_IN', 'PCE_NR',
   'CON_TC_PCE_QT', 'CON_TC_GRS_WT', 'CON_TC_VL', 'PCE_OC_LN', 
   'PCE_OC_WD','PCE_OC_HT', 'PCE_OC_VL', 'PCE_OC_WT', 'PCE_OA_LN', 
   'PCE_OA_WD','PCE_OA_HT', 'PCE_OA_VL', 'PCE_OA_WT', 'COS_EVENT_TD', 
   'COS_EVENT_LT',
   '((XSF_ID||XSS_ID)||XSG_ID)', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_OCC',  
   'PCE_NR.1', 'PCS_EVENT_TD', 'PCS_EVENT_LT',
   '((XSF_ID||XSS_ID)||XSG_ID).1', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_OCC.1', 
   'BUL_CSYS_ID_1', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_2', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_3',
   'BUL_CSYS_ID_4', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_5', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_6', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_7',
   'BUL_CSYS_ID_8', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_9', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_10', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_11',
   'BUL_CSYS_ID_12', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_13', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_14', 
   'BUL_CSYS_ID_15',
   'BUL_CSYS_ID_16', 'CON_TOT_SECT_NR', 'DELAY'] ) 

df = pd.DataFrame(data.values ,columns=data.columns)
for col_name in df.columns:

if(df[col_name].dtype == 'object' and col_name != 'DELAY'):
    df[col_name]= df[col_name].astype('category')
    df[col_name] = df[col_name].cat.codes

   target_attribute = df['DELAY']
   input_attribute=df.loc[:,'CON_ID':'CON_TOT_SECT_NR']

   from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
   X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =               train_test_split(input_attribute,target_attribute, test_size=0.3)

   from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
   rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 1000, random_state = 42)
   rf.fit(X_train, y_train);

   predictions = rf.predict(X_test)

   errors = abs(predictions - y_test)
   print(errors)

   print('Mean Absolute Error:', round(np.mean(errors), 2), 'result.')

   mape = 100 * (errors / y_test)

   accuracy = 100 - np.mean(mape)
   print('Accuracy:', round(accuracy, 2), '%.')

   data_new = pd.read_csv('D:/Users/v477sjp/lpthw/Extract-0401-              TestCurrentData-Null.csv', usecols=['CON_ID','CON_LEGACY_ID','CON_CREATE_TD','CON_CREATE_LT','BUL_CSYS_ID_ORIG',       'BUL_CSYS_ID_CORIG','BUL_CSYS_ID_DEST','BUL_CSYS_ID_CLEAR','TOP_ID', 
   'CON_DG_N', 'PTP_ID', 'SMO_ID_1',
   'SMO_ID_8', 'LOB_ID', 'PRG_ID', 'PSG_ID', 'SMP_ID', 'COU_ISO_ID_ORIG',
   'COU_ISO_ID_DEST', 'CON_DELIV_DUE_DT', 'CON_DELIV_DUE_LT',
   'CON_POSTPONED_DT', 'CON_DELIV_PLAN_DT', 'CON_INTL_IN', 'PCE_NR',
   'CON_TC_PCE_QT', 'CON_TC_GRS_WT', 'CON_TC_VL','PCE_OC_LN','PCE_OC_WD',
   'PCE_OC_HT', 'PCE_OC_VL', 'PCE_OC_WT', 'PCE_OA_LN', 'PCE_OA_WD',
   'PCE_OA_HT', 'PCE_OA_VL', 'PCE_OA_WT', 'COS_EVENT_TD', 'COS_EVENT_LT',
   '((XSF_ID||XSS_ID)||XSG_ID)', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_OCC',  
   'PCE_NR.1','PCS_EVENT_TD', 'PCS_EVENT_LT',
   '((XSF_ID||XSS_ID)||XSG_ID).1', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_OCC.1', 
   'BUL_CSYS_ID_1', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_2', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_3',
   'BUL_CSYS_ID_4', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_5', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_6', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_7',
   'BUL_CSYS_ID_8', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_9', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_10', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_11',
   'BUL_CSYS_ID_12', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_13', 'BUL_CSYS_ID_14','BUL_CSYS_ID_15',
   'BUL_CSYS_ID_16', 'CON_TOT_SECT_NR', 'DELAY'] ) 

   df_new = pd.DataFrame(data_new.values ,columns=data_new.columns)
   for col_name in df_new.columns:
       if(df_new[col_name].dtype == 'object' and col_name != 'DELAY' ):
           df_new[col_name]= df_new[col_name].astype('category')
           df_new[col_name] = df_new[col_name].cat.codes
   X_test_new=df_new.loc[:,'CON_ID':'CON_TOT_SECT_NR']
   y_pred_new = rf.predict(X_test_new)
   df_new['Delay_1']=y_pred_new
   df_new.to_csv('prediction_new.csv')
```

The prediction results are wrong for the new dataset and the accuracy is very low. Accuracy for data is 99%. I should be getting negative results for the new dataset. But all the values I got are positive. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the algorithm is overfitted to the training dataset. Some options to try are
1) Use a larger dataset
2) decrease the features/columns or do some feature engineering 
3) use regularization
4) if the dataset is not too large try decreasing the number of estimators in case of random forest.
5) play with other parameters like max_features, max_depth, min_samples_split, min_samples_leaf

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another clarification. If the alogorithm is not trained with negative values, then will it predict negative values for the new dataset? I used a dataset with 1000 records for training the algorithm and the new dataset contains has 1000 records.

Comment: It is an example of  "Non representative training data". It is crucial to use a training set that is representative of the cases you want to generalize in the future. you should make sure that your training dataset has examples that represents the future new datasets.